# com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)

Tags: python, pywin32

While generating pdf from excel sheet i am getting below error:

```
 ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, save_as)
 File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 5, in ExportAsFixedFormat
 com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)
```

Below is my code:

```
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    logging.debug("Saving excel file {} to file {}".format(filename, save_as))
    books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    ws = books.Worksheets[0]
    ws.Visible = 1
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, save_as)
    books.Close(True)
    xlApp.Quit()
```

It works on my laptop where office 365 is installed however gives above error on another system with Microsoft office 2007 is installed.

Python version : python 2.7
openpyxl : 2.4.5
pywin32: 224

There is not enough documentation. It would be great help if someone can provide pointer to debug it and understand the error.

Answer (score 2):

I have found this related article: [Python Interactions with Excel Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028948/python-interactions-with-excel-macros)
The code there is for python 2. The most important part is that closing the workbook and quitting the app resulted in remained excel workbooks hiddenly open in the background therefore when you want to open the workbook with Excel it can be open for reading only. To completely close all threads do this at the end (Python 3):

```
books.Close(True) 
xlApp.quit()
xlApp = None
del xlApp
```

This way no threads remains and workbook(s) may be open for writing, can be saved...

This may also help in general error code decryption, in Python prompt:

```
import win32api
win32api.FormatMessage([ERRORCODEHERE])
```

for example:

```
import win32api
win32api.FormatMessage(-2147352567)
```

Which may give you more hints on the error (for me it did not).

I found the error to be raised when

1. wrong sheet name is given, so the excel file does not contain such
   worksheet
2. while the script is running and performing tasks on the given
   worksheet it loses somehow the focus. It may happen if you open or
   just click on an excel file meanwhile the script is running, or you
   open several workbooks with the script and it gets lost somehow.

Excel and python api should not have issues to work paralelly, but for me it did somehow.

Make everything step by step: open file->process->close then next...
All in short, check your code and worksheet names first, then go for simplified steps.

Comment: The problem with this though, is that the error is raised on saving as PDF, i.e. *before* closing any workbooks. I'm facing the same error, created a fresh .xlsx document, killed excel completely through the task manager and tried to save it as PDF much like in the question here, and still the error comes up. As a side note, my code ran fine until yesterday, today it crashes with this error and also throws the Excel warning dialogue "Document might be open or not saved properly".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while using xlwings for interacting with Excel. xlwings also use win32com clients in the backend.
I think it is not an Excel version issue.
I realized that this error pops up whenever the code is executed and the excel file (containing data) is not in focus. In order to resolve the issue, I simply select the file which is being processed and run the code and it always works for me.

Comment: Not working for me (with xlwings).