# Python Interactions with Excel Macros

Tags: python, excel, vba

I would like to quit my Excel application from my Python code. My Python code opens an excel book, runs a macro, then closes the book. However, the Excel application is still running. How can I quit Excel?

This is the error I get from Python IDLE:

```
(-2147417848, 'The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.', None, None)
```

Here is my Python Code:

```
import xl


report = xl.Workbook(r"C:\Desktop\Reader.xlsm")
print(report)

report.xlWorkbook.Application.Run('Reader')

report.xlWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges=False)
report.xlWorkbook.Application.Quit()

print("The job is done")
```

Here is my Excel macro:

```
Public Sub Reader()

MsgBox ("Hello World")

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe put `Application.Quit` after `MsgBox ("Hello World")` in your macro?

Comment: @dwirony, You are awesome! I updated my Python code to only run the macro and I made Excel quit the application via the VBA macro. It now runs perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from dwirony is a workaround that is definitely usable. However you really want to go the right way about this or you may end up with a hanged excel process and memory leaks.

In my opinion the correct way would be:

```
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

report = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Reader.xlsm")
xl.Application.Run('Reader')
report.Close False
xl.Application.Quit()
xl = None
del xl

print("The job is done")
```

Comment: When I run your code I get this error: name 'win32com' is not defined.

Comment: I missed the import.

Comment: Awesome! It worked!

However, I did get a python error that says:

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147417848, 'The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.', None, None)

Comment: I should've `set xl = None` before `del xl`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it helped when I had an issue with xlwings!
I have connected your answer with this article: [com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024809), None)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088710/com-error-2147352567-exception-occurred-0-none-none-none-0-214702/72388832#72388832)

The above solution is for python 2. For python 3 it would look like:

```
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
filepath = *INSERTFILEPATHHERE* #for example "C:\Desktop\Reader.xlsm"
report = xl.Workbooks.Open(filepath) 
xl.Application.Run('Reader')
report.close() #empty brackets
xl.Application.quit()
xl = None
del xl

print("The job is done")
```

You may also use xlwings or openpyxl instead of win32com to process your files.