# xlwings: how to merge cells

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm trying to merge cells together using the code below as suggested in the [xlwings github](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/issues/21), but it seems to stuck in some process for a very long time (around 10 minutes before I cancel it)

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('test_merge_cells.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
ws.range('A1:A5').api.merge() # this line is stuck in a process
```

Versions used:
`python` 3.7.11
`xlwings` 0.24.7

The [official doc](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range.merge) also writing the same method to merge cells. But I still can't do it. Is it because I'm using different package version?

Tq in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the “.api” from your code. That is only required for things that are not natively supported.

Comment: Removed the `.api` but raise an exception: com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: After quick google, found similar [xlwings exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55088710/com-error-2147352567-exception-occurred-0-none-none-none-0-214702) which was due to excel not in focus. So removing the `.api` actually works. I will accept this as answer. Tq